# Git cherry pick issue while picking a range of commits

Tags: git, version-control, cherry-pick

Git version 1.7.1 - CentOS 6.6

I am trying to cherry pick a range of commits.

I am in my `feature` branch and the output of `git log` is like below

```
commit: 111
Author: abc
time: xyz

commit: 222
Author: abc
time: xyz

commit: 333
Author: abc
time: xyz

commit: 444
Author: abc
time: xyz

commit: 555
Author: abc
time: xyz
```

And I go back to `master` branch to pick a few commits from `feature` branch.

I want to cherry pick from 444 to 222. So i pass the below command:

```
git cherry-pick 444^..222
```

But I get an error like below:

```
fatal: Cannot find '444^..222'
```

However, I can cherry pick a  single commit. I'm pretty sure that my syntax is correct. I want to include commits 444,333 and 222 to apply in my target branch.

I can successfully do `git show` for both the commits. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you don't want cherrypick you want `rebase --onto master 555 222`. add `-i` for *interactive mode* for more control.

Comment: Will it just merges/copies only the files in those commits? Or will it merge the entire history? Also I am not going to merge both the branches forever!

Comment: *"Will it just merges/copies only the files in those commits?"* sort of, it only copies the *changes* made in this commits.

Comment: *"lso I am not going to merge both the branches forever!"* what does that mean?

Comment: I will not merge the feature branch with master for any reason in future. In that case cherrypick is better?

Comment: *"In that case cherrypick is better?"* there is no difference. in both cases the changes become new commits in the target branch. However, git is smart enough to avoid conflicts with cherrypicked/rebased commits.

Comment: Okay. But few forums say that cherry picking is not good since it creates a new commit # and it is against the principles of versioning... anyway I will go with cherry picking! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git version 1.7.1 does not support cherry-picking a range of commits.  That feature first appeared in Git 1.7.2.

(But any version of Git predating about 2.7 at this point is ancient and you should upgrade.)

Comment: Okay I actually found it myself and yeah you are right. But in CentOS 6.x version 1.7.1 is the highest through yum repo. But I tried with CentOS 7 and found it working. Thanks for the answer!